# TimerTask doesn't take effect

Tags: android, timer, timertask

Here's my code:

```
public class SomeName extends MapActivity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener{
public Timer t1 = new Timer();
public TimerTask tt;
public long interval = 5000;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    timer();
}
public final void timer()
{ 

    t1 = new Timer();
    tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            systemClick();
        }
    };
    t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 10000, interval);
}
 public void systemClick()
{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"System Button Clicked", 5).show();
}
```

Actually, I want to call some function, where I refresh my location.

But I can't understand why I never get the toast on the screen.
I'm new to android.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just so you're aware, you instantiate t1 twice. Can you replace getApplicationContext() with `this`?

Comment: @TusharDhoot, corrected both, still the same.

Comment: Do you get anything in your logcat? It's the error log usually at the bottom of Eclipse.

Comment: @TusharDhoot, look. I have a button on my google maps. When I press it, I get my current location (button click updates my location). Now I want to simulate button click, calling `myButton.performClick()` each 5000ms. Times is created for this. It should call the `systemClick()`, where is located `myButton.performClick()`. But I never get into the `systemClick()`. That's the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use handler in your Activity

```
final Handler handlerforadd = new Handler();
Runnable runnableforadd  = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handlerforadd.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }   
};

handlerforadd.postDelayed(runnableforadd, 0);
```

Comment: The `scheduleAtFixedRate` repeates the function infinitely. As far as I understand this code will be executed one time, won't it?

Comment: The `handerlerforadd.postDelayed(this, 1000)` in the `run()` allows it to run itself again in 1 second

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the Toast has to be done on the UI thread. In your current code the method `run()` is being executed on a separate thread. I would suggest looking at this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) on Processes and Threads. @parag is correct using a Handler is one way to get a reference to the UI thread but there are other methods.

Comment: This exactly. It should have been clear from the Logcat because there is usually a warning or error displayed.